# Importing / bundling Bootstrap 5 or Popper.js with Gulp 4 generates LICENSE.js file?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gulp

I'm using Gulp 4 and Webpack 5 on a Bootstrap 5 project and when I bundle my scripts, Gulp generates a `bundle.js` (as expected) but it also generates a `bundle.js.LICENSE.js` file.

I can't see anything in my build task that would create that.

It only seems to be the case when I `import 'bootstrap'` or `import Popper from 'popper.js/dist/umd/popper'`.

Is there a way to disable the generation of that LICENSE file? I'm guessing there's something in the Bootstrap 5 js that's forcing Gulp or Webpack to create that file(?)

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Here's my build scripts task:

```
// Build Scripts Task
const buildScripts = (mode) => (done) => {
  let streamMode;
  if (mode === 'development') {
    streamMode = require('./webpack/config.development.js');
  } else if (mode === 'production') {
    streamMode = require('./webpack/config.production.js');
  } else {
    streamMode = undefined;
  }
  
  ['development', 'production'].includes(mode) ? pump([
    gulp.src(srcPath('js')),
    vinylNamed(),
    webpackStream(streamMode, webpack),
    gulpSourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }),
    through2.obj(function (file, enc, cb) {
      const isSourceMap = /\.map$/.test(file.path);
      if (!isSourceMap) {
        this.push(file);
      }
      cb();
    }),
    gulpBabel({
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
    }),
    ...((mode === 'production') ? [gulpUglify()] : []),
    gulpSourcemaps.write('./'),
    gulp.dest(distPath('js')),
    browserSync.stream(),
  ], done) : undefined;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addon Webpack uses to optimize files is called Terser and has options to extract inline comments matching a certain pattern to an external file (which by default is that License pattern you are seeing).

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          //...
          extractComments: true
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
}
```

> By default extract only comments using /^**!|@preserve|@license|@cc_on/i regexp condition and remove remaining comments. If the original file is named foo.js, then the comments will be stored to foo.js.LICENSE.txt. The terserOptions.format.comments option specifies whether the comment will be preserved, i.e. it is possible to preserve some comments (e.g. annotations) while extracting others or even preserving comments that have been extracted.

Check in your `config.production.js` webpack file and see if those options are used in there. It does default to `true` though.

Comment: Thank you kindly. That worked, with one change. The plugin docs have the `extractComments: true` directly in the `new TerserPlugin({ extractComments: true}),` It didn't work when inside a `terserOptions: {}}` object.